# Scrapy - dont_filter does not allow me to send requests when set to "False"

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to crawl a website built on localhost using Scrapy.
I'm currently finding some difficulties in understanding the behavior behind "dont_filter": when set to False, no request is ever launched (I've got a BurpSuite proxy on filtering the traffic), and the crawling stops immediately. Instead, when the "dont_filter" is set to True, I end up having a huge HTTP traffic.
This is my current implementation:

```
import scrapy
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs
import sys


class Crawler(scrapy.Spider):
    def __init__(self, cookies=None, proxies=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Crawler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.cookies = cookies if cookies else {}
        self.proxies = proxies
        if "start_urls" in kwargs:
            self.allowed_domains = [
                urlparse(url).netloc for url in kwargs["start_urls"]
            ]

    visited_forms = set()
    name = "website_crawler"

    def parse(self, response):
        try:
            content_type = response.headers.get("Content-Type")
            if not content_type or b"text" not in content_type:
                self.logger.info(f"Skipping non-textual response at {response.url}")
                return
            common_meta = {"dont_verify_ssl": True}

            if self.proxies:
                common_meta["proxy"] = self.proxies

            yield {
                "URL": response.url,
                "Method": "POST" if "POST Params" in response.meta else "GET",
                "GET Params": parse_qs(urlparse(response.url).query),
                "POST Params": response.meta.get("POST Params")
                if "POST Params" in response.meta
                else None,
            }

            for href in response.css("a::attr(href)").getall():
                full_url = response.urljoin(href)
                # Check for 'logout' substring in the full URL
                if "logout" in full_url:
                    continue

                yield scrapy.Request(
                    full_url,
                    callback=self.parse,
                    cookies=self.cookies,
                    meta=common_meta,
                    dont_filter=False,
                )

            for form in response.css("form"):
                formdata = {}
                action = form.css("::attr(action)").get()
                method = form.css("::attr(method)").get() or "GET"
                input_names = []

                for input in form.css("input"):
                    input_name = input.css("::attr(name)").get()
                    input_value = input.css("::attr(value)").get() or ""
                    if input_name:
                        formdata[input_name] = input_value
                        input_names.append(input_name)

                form_fingerprint = (response.url, tuple(sorted(input_names)))
                if form_fingerprint in self.visited_forms:
                    continue

                self.visited_forms.add(form_fingerprint)

                if method.lower() == "post":
                    post_meta = common_meta
                    post_meta["POST Params"] = formdata
                    if "logout" in response.url:
                        continue
                    else:
                        yield scrapy.FormRequest(
                            url=response.urljoin(action),
                            cookies=self.cookies,
                            formdata=formdata,
                            callback=self.parse,
                            meta=post_meta,
                            dont_filter=False,
                        )
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            sys.exit(0)
```

I've built this main to launch the crawler:

```
def main_crawler(args, cookies):
    # Set up Scrapy settings based on the scan type and provided arguments
    try:
        settings = {
            "BOT_NAME": BOT_NAME,
            "SPIDER_MODULES": SPIDER_MODULES,
            "NEWSPIDER_MODULE": NEWSPIDER_MODULE,
            "EXTENSIONS": EXTENSIONS,
            "ROBOTSTXT_OBEY": ROBOTSTXT_OBEY,
            "CONCURRENT_REQUESTS": CONCURRENT_REQUESTS,
            "COOKIES_ENABLED": True if args.cookies else False,
            "DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES": DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES,
            "DOWNLOAD_FAIL_ON_DATALOSS": DOWNLOAD_FAIL_ON_DATALOSS,
            "ITEM_PIPELINES": ITEM_PIPELINES,
            "LOG_LEVEL": LOG_LEVEL,
            "AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED": AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED,
            "AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY": AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY,
            "HTTPCACHE_ENABLED": HTTPCACHE_ENABLED,
            "HTTPCACHE_EXPIRATION_SECS": HTTPCACHE_EXPIRATION_SECS,
            "HTTPCACHE_STORAGE": HTTPCACHE_STORAGE,
            "HTTPCACHE_IGNORE_MISSING": HTTPCACHE_IGNORE_MISSING,
            "HTTPCACHE_DEBUG": HTTPCACHE_DEBUG,
            "HTTPCACHE_IGNORE_HTTP_CODES": HTTPCACHE_IGNORE_HTTP_CODES,
            "REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION": REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION,
            "TWISTED_REACTOR": TWISTED_REACTOR,
            "FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING": FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING,
            "DEPTH_LIMIT": 3
        }

        # Instantiate the CrawlerProcess with the appropriate settings
        logger.info(
            f"Starting crawl of {args.url} with aggressiveness set to: {args.type}... This might take some time\n\n"
        )
        time.sleep(2)
        start_time = time.time()  # Store the start time

        process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
        crawler = process.create_crawler(Crawler)
        process.crawl(
            crawler, start_urls=[args.url], cookies=cookies, proxies=args.proxies
        )
        process.start()  # This will block until the crawl is finished
        # Once the crawling process has completed
        stats = crawler.stats.get_stats()
[...]
```

Where is this issue coming from? I'm new to Scrapy so any help, even suggestions on how to improve my code, will be more than welcomed :)
Thanks everyone!